# How to get PlanEstimate swipe on card

Tags: rally

I searched around, but dont see how to get the PlanEstimate swipe on the cards in a custom Kanban board.

I have overridden the CardContentRight and then tried to set showPlanEstimate, but not no avail.

I see in the documentation there is a setShowPlanEstimate, but again, not sure where to actually put that code to make it come up.

```
    Ext.define('Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.MyCardContentRight', {
        alias: 'plugin.mycardcontentright',
        extend: 'Rally.ui.cardboard.plugin.CardContentRight',
        config : {
            showPlanEstimate: true
        }

    });
```

Probably an easy answer, but I cant seem to show them on my cards. Cant I just set the card somehow to make it show, or do I really have to override CardContentRight to get it to show?

Answer (score 0):

As long as the [fields](https://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc1/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.cardboard.Card-cfg-fields) specified on your card contain PlanEstimate and the data being fetched includes this field it should just work without needing to extend the card content right plugin.